# Best practice to reuse use cases in a clean architecture

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

Imagine a "clean architecture" in which you have two use cases. One of them is `CreateCustomerHandler`, and the other  `SignUpCustomerByGoogleAuthHandler`. So, the `SignUpCustomerByGoogleAuthHandler` has to reuse the `CreateCustomerHandler` to eventually create a `Customer`.

Is it legit to inject `CreateCustomerHandler` to `SignUpCustomerByGoogleAuthHandler` as dependency? Are there any pitfalls?

I read somewhere that it's not recommended to reuse your use cases, but what to do in that simple case? Extract the whole `CreateCustomerHandler` as ***Application Service*** and inject it both to the `CreateCustomerHandler` and `SignUpCustomerByGoogleAuthHandler` use cases?

**CreateCustomerHandler**

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Identity\Application\Customer\UseCase\CreateCustomer;

use App\Identity\Application\Customer\CustomerEntityManager;
use App\Identity\Application\Security\PasswordEncoder;
use App\Identity\Domain\Customer\Customer;
use App\Identity\Domain\Customer\Name;
use App\Identity\Domain\Customer\Username;
use App\Identity\Domain\User\Email;
use App\Identity\Domain\User\Password;

final class CreateCustomerHandler
{
    private CustomerEntityManager $customerEntityManager;

    private PasswordEncoder $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(CustomerEntityManager $customerEntityManagerByActiveTenant,
                                PasswordEncoder $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->customerEntityManager = $customerEntityManagerByActiveTenant;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function handle(CreateCustomerCommand $command): Customer
    {
        $customerId = $this->customerEntityManager->nextId();
        $email = new Email($command->email());
        $username = new Username($command->username());
        $name = new Name($command->firstname(), $command->lastname());
        $password = $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($command->password());
        $password = new Password($password);

        $customer = new Customer(
            $customerId,
            $email,
            $password,
            $username,
            $name,
        );

        $this->customerEntityManager->create($customer);

        return $customer;
    }
}
```

**SignInCustomerByGoogleAuthHandler**

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Identity\Application\Customer\UseCase\SignInCustomerByGoogleAuth;

use App\Identity\Application\Customer\CustomerEntityManager;
use App\Identity\Application\Customer\Query\CustomerByGoogleAuthQuery;
use App\Identity\Application\Customer\UseCase\CreateCustomer\CreateCustomerCommand;
use App\Identity\Application\Customer\UseCase\CreateCustomer\CreateCustomerHandler;
use App\Identity\Application\Security\Security;
use App\Identity\Application\User\UseCase\LinkGoogleAuth\GoogleAuth;
use App\Identity\Domain\Customer\Customer;

final class SignInCustomerByGoogleAuthHandler
{
    private CustomerByGoogleAuthQuery $customerByGoogleAuthQuery;

    private GoogleAuth $googleAuth;

    private CreateCustomerHandler $createCustomerHandler;

    private CustomerEntityManager $customerEntityManager;

    private Security $security;

    public function __construct(CustomerByGoogleAuthQuery $customerByGoogleAuthQuery,
                                CreateCustomerHandler $createCustomerHandler,
                                CustomerEntityManager $customerEntityManager,
                                Security $security,
                                GoogleAuth $googleAuth)
    {
        $this->customerByGoogleAuthQuery = $customerByGoogleAuthQuery;
        $this->googleAuth = $googleAuth;
        $this->createCustomerHandler = $createCustomerHandler;
        $this->customerEntityManager = $customerEntityManager;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function handle(SignInCustomerByGoogleAuthCommand $command): Customer
    {
        $code = $command->code();

        $oauthUser = $this->googleAuth->userByOneTimeCode($code);
        $customer = $this->customerByGoogleAuthQuery->queryByGoogleUser($oauthUser);
        $username = $this->customerEntityManager->nextId()->value();
        $password = $this->security->randomPassword();

        if (!$customer) {
            $command = new CreateCustomerCommand(
                $oauthUser->email(),
                $username,
                $password->hash(),
                $oauthUser->firstname(),
                $oauthUser->lastname(),
            );
            $customer = $this->createCustomerHandler->handle($command);
        }

        // TODO $customer->allowAuthVendor();

        return $customer;
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67671691/best-practice-to-reuse-usecases "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: @gnat sorry, wasn't really sure to which community this question is more related. Let's stick to the SO version or this one?

Comment: Please be clear with your terminology.  A Use Case is not code, it is a description of functionality the application must have to satisfy a user's need.  A handler is code, but depending on whatever your framework is, the nuance of how "Handler" is defined depends on that context.  Code questions on Stack Overflow, Design/Process questions here.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch by UseCase I mean one of app's scenarios, right. Handler is an implementation of that scenario. So I'm talking abstractly from a code.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch This is yet another unfortunate wording used by R.C.Martin in his "[clean architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)", which creates a lot of confusion.  What he calls "use-cases" correspond more to some transactional logic than to anything related to a real use-case...

Comment: Included file sources in the message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clean architecture - How do I deal with use case reuse?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/370168/clean-architecture-how-do-i-deal-with-use-case-reuse)

Comment: @Christophe possibly yes. Got also another few discussions (in another place) and have some understanding so we might close the question.

Comment: Why are you choosing to reuse the use-case instead of just `$customer = new Customer...`? You might find your answer to the above question to be insightful

Comment: @king-side-slide customer creation logic might be not so simple, why to duplicate it?

Comment: @Clark That's a sensible response to my question. But we can do better! Have you thought about _why_ you don't want to duplicate it? Is it because you think the logic might (wait for it) _change_? Do domain objects just appear out of nowhere in your system? Is there another way to encapsulate the logic to create a `Customer` that doesn't require coupling use-cases (and therefore setting a precedent for unbounded data access operations -- i.e. "nested transactions")? You see, I know the answer to your question. But I think you know the answer as well.

Comment: @king-side-slide well, currently my opinion is that we might extract a common logic to the Application or Domain Service layer and reuse it via DI in both these UseCases (which are actually Application Services). Don't you think so?

Comment: @Clark That's exactly right. It could also be a simple as a static factory method defined on `Customer`. Importantly though, we want to make sure the portion of the logic we are abstracting doesn't touch our `CustomerEntityManager`. It's best to keep the outer-most layer of our system as "flat" as possible so that it is easy to glean precisely what's happening when we read our use-case. Yes, that means duplicating the logic to persist our `Customer`! That makes sense considering you have 2 use-cases that create one though doesn't it?